# Quick question on the simplification of digamma series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, integration, summation, gamma-function

How to simplify :
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k-1}}}{k}\left( \psi \left( \frac{k}{2\left( 2+\sqrt{3} \right)}+1 \right)-\psi \left( \frac{k}{2\left( 2+\sqrt{3} \right)}+\frac{1}{2} \right) \right)}$$

Comment: That about the final step of a question...:(